# Remove folder with files inside node js

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to build a code to delete files in node js(without modules/external terminal/cmd commands).

Until now, the best I got(I've search on google and did lots of stuff) was:

```
function rmdir(d) {
    var self = arguments.callee
    if (fs.existsSync(d)) {
        fs.readdirSync(d).forEach(function(file) {
            var C = d + '/' + file
            if (fs.statSync(C).isDirectory()) self(C)
            else fs.unlinkSync(C)
        })
        fs.rmdirSync(d)
    }
}
```

But even though everything here is "sync", when the fs.rmdirSync is executed, it throws an error saying that the folder is not empty(but it is).

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using one of the excellent libraries out there already? Both [rimraf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rimraf) *and* [fs-extra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra) have excellent support for recursive deletion, and can use either synchronous or asynchronous approaches.

As for `Array.forEach`, [the source code for rimraf](https://github.com/isaacs/rimraf/blob/master/rimraf.js#L86) on line 86 shows that `forEach` is used to iterate over the results (though admittedly, if it fails a timeout is set to retry several times). That being said, [performance tests for Array.forEach vs. for](https://jsperf.com/fast-array-foreach) show that the built-in construct runs significantly faster.